# Javascript's offsetWidth not working for Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, polyfills

I have a div in the middle of page that becomes sticky right beneath the header menu on scroll of page. The problem is using offsetWidth doesn't add any width to the corresponding div in Safari, so the width of sticky div does not adapt to the screen size.

I did my search online and saw a few suggestions and hacks (ex: [this link](https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html#webkit)), however none of them really worked in my case.

Since offsetWidth is supposed to be supported by all browsers, I don't see  why Safari has any issue with it. The code is below:

JS:

```
const scheduleControls = document.querySelector('.schedule-controls');
const wrap = document.querySelector('.schedule-controls-wrapper');

function fixControls(){
        const scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
        const wrapOffsetTop = wrap.offsetTop;
         if((document.querySelector('.section-live').offsetTop - 240) <= scrollTop) {
          scheduleControls.classList.remove('fixed');
          scheduleControls.style = '';
        } else  if (scrollTop + document.querySelector('.js_site-header').offsetHeight >= wrapOffsetTop) {
          scheduleControls.classList.add('fixed');
          scheduleControls.style = `width:${wrap.offsetWidth}px;`;
        } else {
          scheduleControls.classList.remove('fixed');
          scheduleControls.style = '';
        }
      }
```

CSS:

```
.schedule-controls {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  transition: all 0.125s ease;

  &.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border-top: 10px solid $white;
    background: $white;

    @media (min-width: $bp-m){
      top: 162px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="schedule-loading-wrapper js_schedule-loading-wrapper hidden">
                <div class="schedule-controls-wrapper" id="scheduleControlsWrapper">
                    <div class="schedule-controls">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed

```
scheduleControls.style = `width:${wrap.offsetWidth}px;`;
```

to

```
scheduleControls.style.width = wrap.offsetWidth + "px";
```

Now it works in Safari and all other browsers.